# Can you define a metric on $(-\infty,0)\cup\mathbb Z^+$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Can you define a metric on $X=(-\infty,0)\cup\mathbb Z^+$ (positive integers)? Would every element of $\mathbb Z^+$ be an isolated point of $X$?

Comment: Do you mean $(-\infty,0)$?

Comment: yes I did, I have made the change

Answer (score 2):

I'll interpret $\mathbb{Z}^+$ as the set $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Now, as $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it of course inherits a metric from $\mathbb{R}$. That is, $X$ is a metric space when given the metric
$$
d(x,y) := |x-y|,
$$
and I leave it to you to check that $d$ indeed defines a metric on $X$. With respect to this metric, every $x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ would be an isolated point of $X$, and every $x \in (-\infty, 0)$ would not be isolated:

- If $x \in (-\infty,0)$, then any open ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ will contain other points of $(-\infty,0) \subseteq X$ (convince yourself of this)
- If $x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then the ball $B(x,1/2) = \{x\}$ cannot contain any other points in $X$.

However, whether or not points in $X$ are isolated depends heavily on the metric we are giving it. The metric described above is the "natural one" inherited from the parent space $\mathbb{R} \supset X$. Were we to instead give $X$ the *discrete metric*
$$
d(x,y) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \neq y,\\
0 & \text{if } x =y,
\end{cases}
$$
then every point in $X$ would be isolated as $B(x,1)$ would simply be equal to $\{x\}$ for every $x \in X$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bijection $f$ from your space to $\Bbb R$. Define a metric $d$ on $X$ by
$$
d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|
$$
and $f$ becomes an isometry. This makes your space essentially equal to $\Bbb R$ with the standard metric, only with different names for all the points. In particular, it will have no isolated points.

Comment: How is $f$ an isometry?

Comment: @Cleric Because $d(x,y)=d_{\Bbb R}(f(x), f(y))$.

Comment: So $f$ is an isometry because $f$ is an isometry? I mean how can $f$ preserve distances when almost every positive real number is removed?

Comment: There is also a bijection from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{10, 20, 30\}$, but said bijection is not an isometry.

Comment: @Cleric It is if you define a new distance function on $\{1,2,3\}$ to be $d(x,y)=|10x-10y|$, assuming $\{10,20,30\}$ has the standard metric. That's what I'm doing here. Any bijection can be made into an isometry if you're willing to base the metric on one of the spaces entirely around making that bijection an isometry.

Comment: Hmm, $\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{10,200,3000,-1\}$.

Comment: So the claim is that both an isometry $f:X\to\mathbb R$ and a metric $d$ on $X$ can always be found such that $d(x,y)=d_\mathbb R(f(x),f(y))$?

Comment: @Cleric the metric is defined to be the one such that $f$ is an isometry, which is clearly possible.

Comment: @Cleric If there is a bijection $X\to Y$, and $Y$ has a metric, then there is exactly one metric on $X$ which makes that bijection into an isometry. If $X$ has some standard metric already, then this new metric might looc very different. And how is your new example of $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}\to \{10, 200, 3000, -1\}$ different from the previous one? The lack of a nice expression for any bijection means the new metric on $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ won't have a nice expression, but _exactly_ the same approach works there.

Comment: It is not obvious to me. I am honestly trying to learn something new with this discussion right now, so I thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Cleric Ok. I'm sorry for my tone. Well, clearly there is a standard metric on $\{10, 200, 3000, -1\}$. And there is a bijection $g:\{1, 2, 3, 4\}\to \{10, 200, 3000, -1\}$. There are 24 bijections, actually, but let's take the one which is implied by the order the elements are written in. So $g(1) = 10, g(2) = 200, g(3) = 3000$ and $g(4) = -1$. Then I can define a metric $d$ on $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ that makes $g$ into an isometry. The short description of that metric is $d(x, y) = |g(x)-g(y)|$. So, for intance, $d(1, 2) = |10-200| = 190$, and $d(3, 4) = |3000 - (-1)| = 3001$.

Comment: This metric has nothing to do with the standard metric on $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. At all. It's a completely new metric, and without the context of $g$ I would go so far as to say it's basically nonsense. But it is a metric, and it makes $g$ into an isometry.

Comment: I see it now. You are right. I was looking at this backward! I also see that the answer to his second question depends on the topology of $X$. Thank you again!

Comment: So, let $X$ be a metric space and $Y$ a of equal cardinal.  Therefore Y is a metric space with Arthur's metric? Is this right?

Comment: @asdf Not automatically. But it can very easily become one, yes.

Comment: So the answer to the question is that any set can have a metric!

Comment: @asdf That's easy: The discrete metric (all distances equal to 1) can be applied to any set. And that's not what the question asks about either, because the question is about a specific set. And the answer to the question is that for that set (and most other sets) there are _many_ metrics, with basically any property you could ask for, as long as the cardinality isn't an obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

Whether $X$ admits a metric and whether $x\in X$ is isolated depends solely on the topology of $X$:

- $X$ with the discrete topology admits a metric and every $x\in X$ is isolated.
- $X$ with the standard relative topology admits a metric and every $x\in\mathbb Z^+$ is isolated.
- $X$ with the trivial topology does not admit a metric.